# If $\left\lbrace X_n \right\rbrace$ be independent $\text{Poiss}(\frac{1}{n})$, is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$ convergent with probability 1?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\left\lbrace X_n \right\rbrace$ be a sequence of independent random variables from the Poisson distribution with parameters $\frac{1}{n}$. Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$ convergent with probability 1?

The suggested approach hints use of Kolmogorov three series theorem.

Comment: Ok, so which constant $c$ would you try to use in the three series theorem?

Comment: Alternative approach: Since $X_n$ is always a nonnegative integer, you could just check if $X_n>0$ for infinitely many $n$, or not.

Comment: $E\left(\sum_{n=1}^N X_n \right)= \sum_{n=1}^N E(X_n)= \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}$ so that $E\left(\sum_{n=1}^N X_n\right)  \rightarrow \infty$ as $N\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: I would try first with $c = 1$ because the parameters (and so expected value and variance for random variable from Poisson distribution) are always less or equal one. The expected value of sum of Poisson random variables is equal to the sum of their parameters, so I have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$, which diverges, thus, from Kolmogorow three series theorem, the sum diverges..?
I have in my notes only "if", not "iff" in the statement of the theorem. Could I use it as above?

Comment: It is easy to show that $P(X_n\ge 1)\sim 1/n$, so \sum P(X_n\ge 1) = \infty$, and the series diverges.